# SwiftUI: Offset Popover Anchor by Constant Amount

Tags: swiftui, popover, anchorpoint

---

## NOTE: This is a macOS question, not iOS.

---

I would like to anchor a SwiftUI Popover exactly 70 points to the right of the bottom-leading corner of the "20 Hours Ago" button in this image:

[image]

I do **NOT** want to anchor the popover a certain *percentage* of the button's width (which would be using `UnitPoint`). The button's text is updated as the user selects different items in the popover and as the button's width changes, the percentage-based anchor point moves, causing the popover to jump around horizontally. No good. I also don't want to anchor the popover exactly at the bottom-leading corner, as that looks dumb.

The trouble is, I can't figure out what to feed SwiftUI to get a constant, simple horizontal offset for the anchor point of the popover. I'm here:

```
.popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover, attachmentAnchor: .point(.bottomLeading), arrowEdge: .bottom, content: {
    ...
})
```

How do I specify: "start at the bottom-leading point and then go 70 points to the right"? (Based on the strings that will appear in the button, I KNOW 70 is a good-looking anchor point for all cases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.rect`:
That defines absolute offsets to the parent content rect, but then you'll have to specify y offset as well.

```
.popover(isPresented: $show1,
         attachmentAnchor: .rect(.rect(CGRect(x: 70, y: 15, width: 0, height: 0))),
         arrowEdge: .bottom)
{
     Text("Popover")
         .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant; thanks! I tried this earlier but got a bunch of compiler gibberish. The double-.rect is apparently what was needed.